# Get the table name when configuring an entity

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

EF Core: I need to get the name of the table as the name of the entity, not dbset, also, I need the `Id` to be `"tableName"+"Id"`.

I have a `DbSet<Country> Countries` - I need table name `Country` and `Id` column (inherited from base entity) to be `CountryId`.

I started with this code that works:

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var builderEntity = modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name);

    // make table name to be entity name
    builderEntity.ToTable(entity.DisplayName());

    // make Id column name to be tableName+Id
    var idProperty = entity.FindProperty("Id");

    if (idProperty != null)
    {
        builderEntity.Property("Id")
            .HasColumnName(entity.GetTableName() + "Id");
    }
}
```

but now I switch to individual configuration.

I have the following:

```
public class IdEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IdEntity
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
        
        // would be better to have the entity TableName, not the Entity name
        // if one day would not be the same...
        var tableName = typeof(TEntity).Name; 

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName(tableName + "Id");
    }
}
```

**Question**: how to get the configured `TableName` (not the entity name) in the code above?

The base class is the following:

```
public class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        var entityName = typeof(TEntity).Name; // here is OK, generic class name
        builder.ToTable(entityName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get the configured TableName (not the Entity name) in the code above?

```
var tn = builder.Metadata.GetTableName();
```

[RelationalEntityTypeExtensions.GetTableName(IEntityType) Method
Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.gettablename?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalEntityTypeExtensions.GetTableName);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0)