# EF trying to create generic type table (TEntity)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I do (ef-core, code-first) the 'by class' configuration starting with a generic base class, like this:

```
public class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        var entityName = nameof(TEntity);
        builder.ToTable(entityName);
    }
}
```

the `add-migration` goes well, but on the `update-database` it complains:

> Cannot use table 'TEntity' for entity type 'Couche' since it is being
> used for entity type 'Affaire' and potentially other entity types, but
> there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'Couche' on the
> primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another
> entity typed mapped to 'TEntity'.

Why should it use table '`TEntity`' when `TEntity` it is a generic type placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nameof(TEntity)` is the string "TEntity".  You should probably use

```
var entityName = typeof(TEntity).Name;
```

Instead.

Comment: oh great sir, please if you could also take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/65984820/961631